# setInterval() that pauses when user leaves the tab?

Tags: javascript

Is there any method in javascript that would behave like setInterval() and would stop when user leave the tab and resume when user enter the tab again?

Comment: Thanks for asking, David, but I think the duplicate question will serve your needs quite well!

Comment: @Bergi The other question asks what browsers do with native `setInterval` when the tab is not active. This question is about an emulation of `setInterval` that forces a pause when the tab becomes inactive. They are not duplicates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create your own API, using [Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API) to detect when the tab becomes visible or hidden, and calling native `setInterval` and `clearInterval` under the hood.

```
var mySetInterval, myClearInterval;
(function() {
  var data = Object.create(null),
      id = 0;
  mySetInterval = function mySetInterval(func, time) {
    data[id] = {
      nativeID: setInterval(func, time),
      func: func,
      time: time
    };
    return id++;
  };
  myClearInterval = function myClearInterval(id) {
    if(data[id]) {
      clearInterval(data[id].nativeID);
      delete data[id];
    }
  };
  document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
    if(document.visibilityState == 'visible')
      for(var id in data)
        data[id].nativeID = setInterval(data[id].func, data[id].time);
    else
      for(var id in data)
        clearInterval(data[id].nativeID);
  });
})();
```

```js
var mySetInterval, myClearInterval;
(function() {
  var data = Object.create(null),
      id = 0;
  mySetInterval = function mySetInterval(func, time) {
    data[id] = {
      nativeID: setInterval(func, time),
      func: func,
      time: time
    };
    return id++;
  };
  myClearInterval = function myClearInterval(id) {
    if(data[id]) {
      clearInterval(data[id].nativeID);
      delete data[id];
    }
  };
  document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
    if(document.visibilityState == 'visible')
      for(var id in data)
        data[id].nativeID = setInterval(data[id].func, data[id].time);
    else
      for(var id in data)
        clearInterval(data[id].nativeID);
  });
})();

var log = document.getElementById('log'),
    timer;
document.getElementById('start').onclick = function() {
  var num = 0;
  myClearInterval(timer);
  timer = mySetInterval(function(){
    log.innerHTML = num++;
  }, 1e3);
};
```

```html
<input id="start" type="button" value="Start" />
<span id="log"></span>
```

Note the API above should not be mixed with the native one, e.g. do not attempt to create with `mySetInterval` and clear with `clearInterval`. Therefore, the IDs returned by `mySetInterval` are deliberately different than the native ones.